# Can I automatically detect and correct unique key violations in EF6?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a very simple scenario.

1. User provides input.
2. Check in DB to see if this input already exists.
3. If it does, use that.
4. If it doesn't, create a new record and use that instead.

The input has a unique constraint in the DB.

Now the issue is that there is a race condition that means that if two people do this at the same time with the same input it is possible for both of them to check the DB and get the answer back that it does not exist in the DB. They will then both create a new record, which the first will be able to insert into the DB, however when the second tries to insert the record it will throw a Unique_Key violation error.

Is it possible to detect this error and then 'correct' it, i.e. grab the record from the DB that was created by the first process and then use that?

Cheers Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like MS SQL then I think the best you could do is first check if that unique entry exists by doing something like:

```
 // See if record exists
 var userInput = context.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(id => id == userInput);
 if (userInput != null)
 {
    userInput = new MyTableEntry();
    // Add entry to DB
    context.MyTable.Add(userInput);

    // There is still the slight possibility of a race condition, but
    // SaveChanges() will throw an exception if there is a unique
    // key violation.
    context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Try to do it twice if there is an key violation (which means you tried to insert the same data twice).  The second time the code runs you are pretty much guaranteed to update the existing db entry.  Its not pretty, but because databases can be accessed by multiple applications you really have to rely on the DB to tell you when you are trying to insert a duplicate record and the only way to do that in EF is by "SaveChanges()"

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, however where you say there is a slight chance of a race condition, actually in my code there is a very large chance of a race condition because there can be a long time (possibly minutes) between the original check and the final SaveChanges. What I need is some code that will detect if SaveChanges throws an exception because of a Unique Key violation and then try to fix it on the fly and the call SaveChanges again. This seems like a common issue, has no one solved this? Or am I thinking of this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using concurrency handling in EF:-

```
try
{
    // Try to save changes, which may cause a conflict.
    int num = context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("No conflicts. " + num.ToString() + " updates saved.");
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
{
    // Resolve the concurrency conflict by refreshing the 
    // object context before re-saving changes. 
    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders);

    // Save changes.
    context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("OptimisticConcurrencyException "  + "handled and changes saved");
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738618(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: All of the examples I can find about concurrency handling in EF show it working on two processes that have made changes to an existing object in the DB. My issue is different in that the object does not yet exist in the DB, but two separate processes are trying to create on object with the same value in a field with a Unique Index on it. Can concurrency be used to solve that scenario as well? In which case can you please show me some examples?